# Compare two sets of text and pull over if a difference

Tags: excel, vba

I am comparing two sets of text (2 different cells) and if they do not match, then I want to bring over the new data as a new line.

I have an existing code that has done great comparing two different sets of data and if it varies (usually numbers, dates, or number with letters i.e. ABC456) then it pulls over the new line of data and inserts it as a new line into my worksheet. However, I now want to compare a thread of text (Several words, numbers, symbols) to see if it varies from what is on that line before and if different then pull it over. Do I need to do something different for my `And .Cells(i, 12) = laws.Cells(j, 12)` part of my code? Thanks.

```
        Sub CompareSheets()

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

            Dim laws As Worksheet
            Set laws = Sheets("LOB")
            Dim interiorws As Worksheet
            Set interiorws = Sheets("copy")

            Dim RowsMaster As Integer, Rows2 As Integer
            RowsMaster = laws.Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Rows2 = interiorws.Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            ' Get the number of used rows for each sheet


            With Worksheets("copy")
         For i = 2 To Rows2
                ' Loop through Sheet 2
                    For j = 2 To RowsMaster
                    ' Loop through the Master sheet
                        If .Cells(i, 3) = laws.Cells(j, 3) And .Cells(i, 5) = laws.Cells(j, 5) And .Cells(i, 6) = laws.Cells(j, 6) And .Cells(i, 7) = laws.Cells(j, 7) And .Cells(i, 12) = laws.Cells(j, 12) Then
                        ' If a match is found:
                            laws.Cells(j, 5) = .Cells(i, 5)
                            ' Copy in contact info
                            Exit For
                            ' No point in continuing the search for that company
                        ElseIf j = RowsMaster Then
                        ' If we got to the end of the Master sheet
                        ' and haven't found a company match
                            RowsMaster = RowsMaster + 1
                            ' Increment the number of rows
                            For k = 1 To 12 ' Change 3 to however many fields Sheet2 has
                                laws.Cells(RowsMaster, k) = .Cells(i, k)
                                laws.Range(laws.Cells(j + 1, 1), laws.Cells(j + 1, 11)).Interior.ColorIndex = 24
                                ' Copy the data from Sheet2 in on the bottom row of Master
                            Next
                        End If
                    Next j
                Next i
            End With

        interiorws.Delete

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        End Sub
```

Comment: Does your text thread contain carriage returns/line feeds or extra spaces. I'm confused as to why a potentially longer thread of text with characters other than numbers/letters creates a different challenge.

Comment: What happens when you try that change?